# Command substitution in bash vs function calling

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a shell script from a book, and there is an example where I am creating a function and invoking that function later with `$(function_name)`.

But as far as I know, I can invoke a function by just writing its name.
So, what is the difference between calling a function with its name and with `$(function_name)`?

Comment: `$( )` captures the output of a command (could be a function, regular command, compound command like a pipeline, or whatever) and uses it as part of another command. See [this Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440088/what-is-command-substitution-in-a-shell).

Answer (score 2):

`$(...)` is called command substitution.

Simply put, `function_name` will print the output, done.

`$(function_name)` the output from the function will become a part (usually as an argument) as a new command to be executed.

```
echo "ls"  #<--- assume this is the function
```

Open a terminal, and give this a try, you will understand it better:

```
echo "ls"
```

and

```
$(echo "ls")
```